# Java - Using Callable void to parse method

Tags: java, switch-statement, callable

I've got the following code:

```
    private static void createMenu(String nameOfMenu, Callable<Void> case1, Callable<Void> case2, Callable<Void> case3 )  throws Exception{
            System.out.println(nameOfMenu+" Options");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?(Type the appropriate slection number)");
            System.out.println("(1) Add "+nameOfMenu);
            System.out.println("(2) Edit "+nameOfMenu);
            System.out.println("(3) Remove "+nameOfMenu);
            System.out.println("(4) Return to Main Menu");
            System.out.println("To quit the program, type 'Q'");
            String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            while (!"1".equals(input) && !"2".equals(input) && !"3".equals(input) && !"4".equals(input) && !"q".equals(input)) {
                System.err.println("Please enter 1, 2, 3, 4 or 'q' only");
                input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            }
            switch (input) {
                case "1":
case1.call();
                    break;
                case "2":
case2.call();
                    break;
                case "3":
case3.call();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    mainMenu();
                    break;
                case "q":
System.exit(0);
                    System.out.println("Thank you!");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I've got a second method that is trying to call the method above

```
private static void callingMethod(){
createMenu("menu name",method(),method1(),method2());
}
```

all the methods are static void.
Netbeans gives me an error saying 'void' type is not allowed here.
how can i fix this error?

Comment: what method(), method1() and method2() returns? void? or Callable? They should give you the Callable, if they return void you are doing it wrong. Post one of them so we can say.

Comment: they are void methods with no returns in them

Comment: *Where* exactly is it saying that `void` is not allowed? Can you provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem? (Most of the code here is irrelevant.)

Comment: Also, which version of Java are you using? With Java 8 you could use method references which will make this simpler...

Comment: As a side note,  a better approach could be to create a common interface for the executions, and implement them as classes, instead as method with an execution method. You could create a hash with keys: "1","2","3" and values the commands and avoid the switch/cases by doing commands.get(input).execute()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) is not a method. It is an interface. So try something like this:

```
class MyTask implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // do something

        return null;
    }
}

...

private static void callingMethod() {
    createMenu("menu name", new MyTask(), new MyTask(), new MyTask());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If readability is not a priority, you can use anonymous classes:

```
createMenu("menu name",
     new Callable<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            method();
            return null;
        }

    },
    new Callable<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            method1();
            return null;
        }

    },
     new Callable<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            method2();
            return null;
        }

    });
```